# In Python how to get the default value of a variable from a Jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2

I need to retrieve from the template that the default value of variable `var_name` is `world`

```
from jinja2 import Template

j2_template = Template("Hello {{ var_name|default('world', true) }} ")

print(j2_template.render())
```

Is this feasible?

Comment: all calculations you should do before using template. When you use template then it is too late for this - and it would need to use string's functions or regex to search text in template, and this can be complex task.

Comment: Obviously, all calculations are done beforehand. This is true for standard values but not for the default values, those are only in the template and I think it should be possible to list all variables of a template including their default values through the Environment and Context Jinja2 classes. I tried to access the Context of a template but without success. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#the-context

Comment: I would rather create variable `var_name = None` at the beginning of code, and before `Template` I would check if it still `None` or not. So all calcuations I would do before rendering template.